# Testing schema action buttons from self

Tags: google-schemas

I tried running the test script on script.google.com ( https://developers.google.com/gmail/schemas/apps-script-tutorial ), and while the email sent, the action button wasn't enabled.

I'm wondering if this is because I am logged in as a google apps user (me@mydomain.com). I see SPF pass and DKIM in the mail headers, and I do see other action buttons in my google apps gmail.

```
Delivered-To: me@mydomain.com
Received: by 10.49.47.9 with SMTP id z9csp53721qem;
        Wed, 12 Jun 2013 09:56:05 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.182.126.226 with SMTP id nb2mr15714364obb.34.1371056165241;
        Wed, 12 Jun 2013 09:56:05 -0700 (PDT)
Return-Path: <3JKi4UQUJBekOLcjYOLcjY.YPeOLcjYOLcjY.YPe@maestro.bounces.google.com>
Received: from mail-oa0-x246.google.com (mail-oa0-x246.google.com [2607:f8b0:4003:c02::246])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id r7si17176840obg.111.2013.06.12.09.56.04
        for <me@mydomain.com>
        (version=TLSv1 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA bits=128/128);
        Wed, 12 Jun 2013 09:56:05 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of 3JKi4UQUJBekOLcjYOLcjY.YPeOLcjYOLcjY.YPe@maestro.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4003:c02::246 as permitted sender) client-ip=2607:f8b0:4003:c02::246;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of 3JKi4UQUJBekOLcjYOLcjY.YPeOLcjYOLcjY.YPe@maestro.bounces.google.com designates 2607:f8b0:4003:c02::246 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=3JKi4UQUJBekOLcjYOLcjY.YPeOLcjYOLcjY.YPe@maestro.bounces.google.com
Received: by mail-oa0-f70.google.com with SMTP id i4so1520067oah.9
        for <me@mydomain.com>; Wed, 12 Jun 2013 09:56:04 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=google.com; s=20120113;
        h=mime-version:message-id:date:subject:from:to:content-type
         :x-gm-message-state;
        bh=nniz4GW4RjisC3jKnq4Um4I4sY/FfW0e4vae0CbzrBM=;
        b=ZdAFsXiPt/07HwxkeNc1VDF+5XzOKT73W9gweiNQOiyeixAVYoLpmlrRWY6XXo3X1j
         O/kHu7wMMNJI84Pcv4GLB8LmIedGKTgKYvo+WIx9FAfZxYf2zW41mwPh7GysdZQ7RivF
         1euibwDPLypdd89MSTCSA3MBk62VnpExUMra0Og0yPjGszqIYW/Jt0YAREGP7ldOr/7j
         K0b/Fi3XB11sG+3ywu3ctNs+7RzZ7IyV3pXGEV6OvMjkZzOX+NnnXVqw8ZoAHm1wJHIc
         iqQrhiZ0AeT8HGip+lfbPrSuH5PLF1CtGlFce9GUCqIWWy/TiiVQ5Hat7I9cN/uuo7aO
         RDqg==
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.182.56.200 with SMTP id c8mr4437548obq.33.1371056164810;
 Wed, 12 Jun 2013 09:56:04 -0700 (PDT)
Message-ID: <001a11c2c236ac8fb004def7e33f@google.com>
Date: Wed, 12 Jun 2013 16:56:04 +0000
Subject: Test Actions in the Inbox - Wed Jun 12 2013 09:56:04 GMT-0700 (PDT)
From: me@mydomain.com
To: me@mydomain.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11c2c236ac8fa304def7e33c
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQk0dwVXVKag+tFK/DdT/gjAPLfjoz8w8Rfbzz8Q2GT0xh0oIly9+Yi2acnPA69hEefyluux

--001a11c2c236ac8fa304def7e33c
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1; format=flowed; delsp=yes

This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.

--001a11c2c236ac8fa304def7e33c
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1

<html>
  <head>
    <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context":       "http://schema.org",
      "@type":          "EmailMessage",
      "description":    "Check this out",
      "action": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "url":   "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eH8KwfdkSqU"
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>
      This a test for a Go-To action in Gmail.
    </p>
  </body>
</html>
--001a11c2c236ac8fa304def7e33c--
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Apps domain get updates on a different schedule than Gmail users and actually the domain administrators can choose to be on the Scheduled Release Track or the Rapid Release Track for updates:

http://whatsnew.googleapps.com/release-tracks

I guess your domain is on the Scheduled Release Track and the support for Actions hasn't rolled out yet.

Comment: I see other actions in my inbox, it's just the one from the test script that I don't see.

Comment: Interesting, I just tried the same markup and the button showed up correctly.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I'm testing in my company's gmail domain and is not working, meanwhile in my personal account is working fine.